# URL Routing Not Working (asp.net 4.5, webforms)

Tags: url, routes

I've been trying to figure out how to get URL routing to work on my box all evening. I'm pretty sure I'm doing things according to the online tutorials (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd329551%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but for some reason it's not working.

This is what I currently type in the address bar: /MA1/DoSurvey.aspx?id=42

But I want the URL to work like this: /MA1/DoSurvey/42

According to the tutorial I have to modify:

## 1: Global.asax.cs by adding

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

into the Application_Start method

## 2: RouteConfig.cs by adding

```
routes.MapPageRoute("","DoSurvey/{id}","~/MA1/DoSurvey.aspx");
```

into the RegisterRoutes method

## 3: Add

```
using System.Web.Routing;
```

as a reference in the DoSurvey.aspx page and then

## 4: Grab the querystring variable by using

```
string SurveyIdQueryStringValue = Page.RouteData.Values["id"] as string;
```

in the DoSurvey.aspx page

what am I missing?

Comment: Does `DoSurvey/42` or `/MA1/DoSurvey/42` goto the aspx page?

Comment: in the code behind i coded it so that it will redirect back to the main page any time the id is null and that's what's happening.

Comment: I did find a nicer way to do it using friendlyurls as in (http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/using-friendly-urls-in-asp.net-web-forms.htm). that seems to work

Answer (score 1):

I Add this code to web.config and everything worked fine, try it

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</modules>
<handlers>
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```